# Customize Collapse Menu - custom bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm generating a custom version of bootstrap. Where can I find the options to change the Collapse Menu background color, border color and active background color?

Comment: Already tried http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ ? It should be somewhere in the source less files

Comment: @IkoTikashi: thanks. Yes, that's what I'm trying... but I'm unable to find the options to make these changes.

Comment: you can always change the CSS and recompile it using LESS.

Comment: there are some variables, but not for every single element, you can easily add your own variables or you add the needed changes to the CSS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a media query to place the following **CSS** rules:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {}
```

**Collapse background color**:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  background: red;
}
```

**Border**:

```
.navbar-default div.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid yellow;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

**Active class**:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active{
    color: #000;
    background: blue;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #000;
    background: blue;
}
```

See **[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPoLEg)**.